# Attach two arrays

Tags: java

I have two Entities User(Id,name, address, contact, degree id, name)and degree(id, name, duration, status). Now I need to return user info along with degree status). I am new to this ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<User> users = userrepo.findAll(Specs.NameStartWith(name));
```

Comment: Hint: Create a new class that has all the desired output attributes. Iterate through the two lists and merge the attributes in one object as per your desired behaviour.

Comment: can you help me with the code

Comment: try something at least will help you @ramu

Comment: I am new to this has no idea how to do

Comment: I created a model with all output attributes. How to compare values between lists

Comment: whatever you tried add it here @ramu

Answer (score 0):

Update the User entity (object) to (Id,name, address, contact, degree, name). I assume this is an ORM you're using. Map the User object to the Degree object and the ORM will make an extra call to the DB to retrieve data from Degree.

Then you can just get status from User.degree....

If you're looking for the code, search for hibernate mapping in Java and you will see tutorials with explanatory code.

Comment: ORM? Hibernate? The OP first needs to learn what a `List` is and how to iterate over it.

Comment: @Kartik  I think he needs to learn software development, then Java, then ORM, then he can think about List for this case... His design points to ORM (calling it entities) that's why I assumed he is dealing with ORMs and has nothing to do with List. The List is what is returned when he does findAll, but adding degree.status to the User, he has to understand ORM